# Insert dialog box in Power Automate flow

Tags: dialog, power-automate

I have a flow triggered by *When an item or a file is modified*.

I am trying to insert a dialog box into the flow so that the user can choose if the update is to be routed to review or not (boolean yes/no). Illustration below.

In Power Automate Desktop there is a *Display Message* action that can add a dialog box to do this. But I cannot find an equivalent action in Power Automate itself.

Is there a way of doing this in non-desktop Power Automate? Or can I somehow integrate the desktop action into my flow?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it's possible but the resulting approach will depend on your technology stack.

You can't pop up a dialog box persay (unless you use PowerAutomate Desktop but I wouldn't recommend that approach) but you can present users with a prompt that allows them to reply and you to capture the output.

---

#### Microsoft Teams

If you use Teams at your org, my suggestion is a basic **Adaptive Card**.  You need to design it (https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) and then use the following operation to make it appear ...

[image]

#### Outlook (Actionable Messages)

This is an alternative approach but is a little more involved.  You can actually customise the body of an email to be interactive but it requires you to setup an endpoint that will receive the response, therefore, making it a lot more involved.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/

---

I'd start with either of those approaches given you have the Microsoft tech stand at hand.

Comment: Thanks @Skin I will follow your advice!